# How to set a dynamic var in another namespace

Tags: clojure

I am trying to define a dynamic var in a different namespace. The Lobos documentation states:

> By default all migrations are kept in the lobos.migrations namespace.
>   It'll get automatically loaded by migration commands, so there's no
>   need to load it yourself. Thus, to use another namespace you must
>   change the lobos.migration/*migrations-namespace* dynamic variable.

I can't figure out how to set the dynamic variable from within my new namespace.

I can do this in the repl via (ns `lobos.migration), but running this cmd from my own ns

```
(def ^:dynamic lobos.migration/*migrations-namespace* 'gb.install.migrations)
```

yields `Can't create defs outside of current ns`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Clojure vars can have a root binding that is visible to all threads.  Additionally, dynamic vars can also have per-thread bindings, each visible to only one thread.

You can temporarily create a per-thread binding for your current thread by using `binding`:

```
(binding [lobos.migration/*migrations-namespace* 'gb.install.migrations]
  ;; binding is in effect here in the body of the binding form
  )
```

Or if a per-thread binding is already in effect, you can change its value using `set!`:

```
(set! lobos.migration/*migrations-namespace* 'gb.install.migrations)
```

But it's likely you'll need to change this particular dynamic var in a way visible across all threads.  If this is true, you'll need to change its root binding by doing something like this:

```
(alter-var-root #'lobos.migration/*migrations-namespace*
                (constantly 'gb.install.migrations))
```

Note I don't know anything about lobos itself and so can't say with certainty that any of these will actually set the var in the way lobos desires.

Comment: Big vote up, Chouser, but wow--that last version is incredibly baroque, for an operation that I would think would occur routinely, even though relatively rarely.  Global parameter settings shouldn't be used a lot, but they have their place.  For example, to change the output width of `pprint`, I can set `clojure.pprint/*print-right-margin*`, but the `alter-var-root` method described above is the only method I've gotten to work.